# What do mysql, postgresql, and Oracle sql use for their command line clients, if not ODBC?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

> `sqlcmd` uses **ODBC** to execute Transact-SQL batches.

I wonder what APIs are used by the command line clients of mysql, postgresql, and Oracle sql. ODBC, JDBC, or ...?

Thanks.

Comment: MySql use `mysql` command, Oracle uses `sqlplus` and postgresql uses `psql`

Comment: ... or its own client libraries (`libmysql`, `oci`, `libpq` `.dll/.so/.dynlib`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the databases you mention use their own protocol for client-server communication.

For [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_PROTOCOL.html) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html) these are documented, while as far as I know Oracle's protocol is not published.